# Combine two queries in one datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb

My app connects to excel files via openfiledialog. I have two searches, primary search and secondary. I would like to get their result in one datagridview. My code (primary search):

```
private void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + testcb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "$] where [" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "] = '" + textBox5.Text + "'", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And secondary search:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + testcb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "$] where [" + addcb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "] = '" + addtb.Text + "'", conn);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In secondary search, instead of:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;
```

Try:

```
DataTable combinedData = (DataTable)(dataGridView2.DataSource);
combinedData.Merge(ds);
dataGridView2.DataSource = combinedData;
```

You might also have to take care of avoiding duplicates in your new datasource. Also: I did not test this solution, its just an idea.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 DataTables lets say `dt1`, `dt2` and a merged `dtAll`. You can then merge the 2 and set it to the DataSource

```
private UpdateDataSource()
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView2.Refresh();
    dtAll.Clear();

    if(dt1 == null && dt2 != null)
    {
        dtAll = dt2;
    }
    else if(dt2 == null && dt1 != null)
    {
        dtAll = dt1;
    }
    else if(dt1 != null && dt2 != null)
    {
        dtAll = dt1.Copy();
        dtAll.Merge(dt2);
    }
    else
    {
        dtAll = null;
    }
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dtAll;
}
```

Your event handlers should become something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + testcb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "$] where [" + addcb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "] = '" + addtb.Text + "'", conn);
        dt2.Clear();
        da.Fill(dt2);
        UpdateDataSource();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `merge`. There is a tutorial for it [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/merging-multiple-datatables-into-single-datatable-using-asp/)